# Proving that $\sqrt{1 + x^2}$ is not a polynomial function

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The given task goes as follows:

> Show that $ f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \sqrt{1 + x^2} $ is not a polynomial function.

I tried this approach - if $f(x)$ is a $n$-degree polynomial function, then the $(n+1)$-st derivative equals to 0 and I was trying to determine the $k$-th derivative of $f(x)$ (and show it differs from 0 for any $k$) but without success. Since $f(x)$ is continuous and defined over whole R domain, I have no idea how to carry on. Any ideas?

Comment: Your idea isn't bad, but taking those derivatives does get difficult.  How about a Taylor series?  For a polynomial, it necessarily terminates.

Comment: I don't get the downvote.  A decent effort (one that is not a bad idea at all) is shown.

Comment: Suppose it *were* a polynomial, then $f^2(x)=P^2(x)$. Try to find such a $\,P(x)\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Oh, that's nice.

Comment: If $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ were a polynomial it would be a linear polynomial. But linear polynomials are injective while $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ is not.

Answer (score 10):

Suppose it is a polynomial, then $$\sqrt{1+x^2}= ax^n+...+b$$

so $$1+x^2= (ax^n+...+b)^2 = a^2x^{2n}+...$$

Since polynomial are equal iff they have same degree we have $2=2n$ so $n=1$ and now we have 
 $$ 1+x^2 = (ax+b)^2 = a^2x^2+2abx+b^2 \implies ab = 0$$
a contradiction, since $|a|=|b|= 1$.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose $f$ is a polynomial,namely  $$f(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}={a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n}=p(x)$$ for some  $n$. Then $$\frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{p(x)}{x}$$ for all non zero $x$. Hence $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{p(x)}{x}=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}=1$$

which means $p(x)$ and $x$ are polynomials of same degree, a contradiction!

Comment: Technically, one should need to check that $a_1=1$ doesn't work, but of course that's easy :)

Answer (score 7):

Alt. hint: following up on OP's idea to use derivatives, note that $\,f(x) \cdot f'(x) = x\,$, but the only polynomials which satisfy that identity are $\,f(x)=\pm x\,$ (*why?*).

Alternatively, show that there exists no polynomial $\,f\,$ such that $\,f^2(x)=x^2+1\,$.

Answer (score 4):

Another demonstration:

A polynomial of degree one or higher when squared, should result in a polynomial that has all its roots double or more than doubles.

$f ^ 2 = x ^ 2 + 1 = (x + i) (x-i)$

That has two roots but they are not equal. And by the fundamental theorem of algebra, that factorization is unique.

Therefore f can not be a polynomial.

Comment: Nice generalisation. $(+1)$ :D

Answer (score 2):

The limit of the function $f(x)$ when $x$ tends to infinity is $x$.
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = x$$

Therefore, either the function $f(x)$ is a first degree polynomial or it is not a polynomial.

Also, $f ^ 2$ must be $x ^ 2 + 1$.

The polynomials of the first degree squared are either simply $x ^ 2$ or have a component $x$ other than zero:
$$ (x+a)^2 = x^2 + 2ax +a^2 $$

Therefore $f (x)$ is not a first degree polynomial ($f^2$ it has no $x$ component, and is not $ x^2 $).

And since it can not have more degrees, $f (x)$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: Strictly speaking, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)=x$ is nonsense.  You likely mean that it grows like $x$.  Perhaps you could make what you mean clearer?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $\sqrt{x^2+1}= a_nx^n+...a_1x +a_0$ , with an $a_n \not =0$.

Since $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ is an even function, the polynomial has to be even, i.e. only even powers occur.

Set $y^2:=x^2+1$, $y \ge 1$, then

$y = a_{2k}(y^2-1)^{2k} + ........+a_0.$

RHS: A polynomial in $y$ with even powers.

LHS: $y$.

A contradiction.